# Chapter heading size in Bianchi

Tags: chapters

I am typing out my dissertation and my supervisor has informed me that the headings of my chapters are too big. I would like to be able to change them but I'm not sure which commands to add in my preamble. My MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[left=3.50cm, right=3.0cm, top=3.0cm, bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\rhead{\thepage}
\fancyheadoffset{0\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\nouppercaseheads
\chapterstyle{bianchi}
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection} 
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\begin{document}
\chapter{introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the running heads in the header on the non-first-page of each `\chapter`?

Comment: @Werner basically I want to change the chapter title font size like for instance the chapter title 'introduction'

Comment: An alternative approach is to use `\chapter[<toc title>][<header title>]{<actual title>}` instead of trying to make some longer-than-needed title fit within the header. Moreover, the chapter title should be able to run across multiple lines without problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (after correcting any typos):

```
\documenclass[11pt,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\chapterstyle{bianchi}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Standard Bianchi Style}

% orginal font specs for the name, number and title
%\renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\Large\sffamily\itshape}
%\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\huge}
%\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\sffamily}

% use smaller fonts (or to what you want)
\renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\large\sffamily\itshape}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\Large}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily}

\chapter{Modified Bianchi Style}

\end{document}
```